# Cannot modify the return value of 'expression' because it is not a variable in a list but an array works

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, value-type

Why do I get the [CS1612](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wydkhw2c.aspx) error on a list of structs with value types as properties but not on an array?

For example:

```
        List<VertexPositionColorTexture> y = new List<VertexPositionColorTexture>();
        y[0].Position = Vector3.Left; // CS1612
        VertexPositionColorTexture[] x = new VertexPositionColorTexture[4];
        x[0].Position = Vector3.Down; // fine
```

Both try to modify a value type so why does the array works?

Comment: Is `VertexPositionColorTexture` struct?

Comment: @Roma yes. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.vertexpositioncolortexture.aspx

Comment: yes it is struct thus the error, @kuhaku structs are value type and immutable so you can not change them, i believe when you change field of struct in array it will return a new one, so that has no effect after all. Interesting btw

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary "structs are value type and *immutable*"? Any chance to provide link explaining that?

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary so this `x[0].Position = Vector3.Down;` creates a completely new `VertexPositionColorTexture`?